# Calculation of equilibrium constant given the reaction temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

I have only a chemical equation, like:
$$\ce{N2 + 3H2 <=> 2NH3}$$
How can I calculate the value of equilibrium constant from only this equation. Provided temperature is $\pu{298K}$. I can use other standard data. I am really stumped on this question.

Comment: You get the equilibrium constant by dividing the concentrations on the right side with the concentrations on the left side. Note that you should  account for the coefficients by using them as powers in your equilibrium equation.

Comment: Use $K= \frac{(NH_3)^2 }{ (N_2)  (H_2)^3}$ where the brackets indicate concentration.

Comment: there is no concentration given

Comment: Note that the standard Gibbs free energy of formation for everything on the left side is zero. The total change in free energy in this reaction is just double whatever the standard Gibbs free energy of formation of ammonia is.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. The concentration is not given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

[By definition](http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05915.html), the standard equilibrium constant is:

$K = e^{-\Delta_rG/RT}$

Where $\Delta_rG$ is the difference between the Gibbs Energies of the products and reactants.

Comment: I need the value of equilibrium constant.

Comment: Don't you want to calculate it from standard Gibbs energy tables?

Comment: Maybe I can use standard Gibbs energy table. I was looking for an direct method. But now it seems that there is no way of getting the value of  $K_c$ without knowing concentrations or Gibbs energy change.